# Asynchronus in JSONP. Functions run just once instead of twice

Tags: jquery, jsonp

My document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     var apiKey = "58e278fc-9d57-49bb-be96-9e85b847d5b5";

     $("a#showA").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         getHotelInfo(apiKey);
     });
});
```

I call JSON API to get Contract names (2 of them)

```
function getHotelInfo(yourAPIKey) {
var enquiry = "http://api.roomex.com/api/hotel?apiKey=" + yourAPIKey;
//alert(enquiry);
 $.ajax({
 url: enquiry,
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: "jsonp",
 jsonp: "callback",
 jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback2",
 complete: function (response, responseCode) {
 },
 success: function (json) {
       $.each(json.Contracts, function (index, contract) {
         getAvailability(yourAPIKey, contract.ContractCode, startDate, endDate);
         getRates(yourAPIKey, contract.ContractCode, startDate, endDate);
         //alert(contract.ContractCode + " - done ");
       });
     }
 });
 }
```

Both functions: getAvailability and getRates - should run twice. It works with little delay (if i put that alert) The problem happends when I remove that alert.

Here are those 2 functions and third one - to populate results/

```
function populateValues(Type, Contractname, RoomType, Date, val) {
$("input#" + Type + "_IE-ORK-IN-32966275_" + Contractname + "_" + RoomType + "_" + Date).val(val);
// alert("input#" + Type + "_" + Contractname + "_" + RoomType + "_" + Date + " -> " + val);
}

function getRates(yourAPIKey, contractCode, startDate, endDate) {
 var ratesEnquiry = "http://api.roomex.com/api/rate?apiKey=" + yourAPIKey + "&contractCode=" + contractCode + "&startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate;

 $.ajax({   
     url: ratesEnquiry,
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: "jsonp",
     jsonp: "callback",
     jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback3",
     complete: function (response, responseCode) {
         //console.log(response); console.log(responseCode);
         //alert("complete");           
     },
     success: function (json) {
         $.each(json, function (index, value) {
             populateValues("rate", this.ContractCode, this.RoomTypeCode, this.Date.substr(0, 10), this.RoomPrice);
             populateValues("hrate", this.ContractCode, this.RoomTypeCode, this.Date.substr(0, 10), this.RoomPrice);                 
         });
     }, 
 });
}



function getAvailability(yourAPIKey, contractCode, startDate, endDate) {
var availabilityEnquiry = "http://api.roomex.com/api/availability?apiKey=" + yourAPIKey + "&contractCode=" + contractCode + "&startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate;
$.ajax({
    url: availabilityEnquiry,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback",
    complete: function (json, responseCode) {
        //console.log(response); console.log(responseCode);
        //alert("complete");           
    },
    success: function (json) {
        $.each(json, function (index, value) {
            //populateAvailability(this.Date.substr(0, 10), this.RoomTypeCode, this.ContractCode, this.Quantity);
            populateValues("avail", this.ContractCode, this.RoomTypeCode, this.Date.substr(0, 10), this.Quantity);
            populateValues("havail", this.ContractCode, this.RoomTypeCode, this.Date.substr(0, 10), this.Quantity);              
        });
    }, async: false
});
}

var startDate = "2012-07-24";
var endDate = "2012-07-31";
```

Problem occurs because od asynchronus. But I have no clue how can I fix that. Could you guys help me please?

Comment: Is that really the actual code you have? Because with the syntax errors it shouldn't run at all.

Comment: @Juahan I've replaced code, Could you check it again please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait when first async request is Done, then execute second and then show results.

E.g:

```
async_func1(async_func2(function(result){
//show results
}));
```

Where async_func1 firsts parameter is callback when request is done.

Comment: But how can I return a few variables ? Let's say that getHotelInfo gives my 2 different contract. How can i pass them as parameter to next function?

Comment: Create global (I know sounds bad) variable where store contract count, create second variable (also global in this scope) who you increment, so with initial value 0. After each request execution, when request is executed - increment second variable and check whether count is equal with first variable where you store total count. If variables are equal - show results or do something else... but imagine situation when api return 20 or 100 contracs - user will wait... maybe you need some other solution how to represent data? Think about this.